# Cannot find module 'joi' from index.js when running Jests tests in Jenkins

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins, jestjs, joi

I'm trying to have my Jest tests (unit tests) for my React code (frontend) run as part of my Jenkins pipeline. When the tests run in dev they work fine without any issues. However, when running in Jenkins the following error is shown for ALL my tests, eg.:

```
FAIL js/components/Common/__tests__/dateTimePickerFormControl.spec.js
● Test suite failed to run
Cannot find module 'joi' from 'index.js'

 at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:191:17)at Object.<anonymous> (../db/models/User/index.js:3:13)
```

I've added **joi** into my **package.json** and even ran npm install for joi as part of the jenkins step to ensure I have the package. Additionally, I've confirmed inside **/node_modules** directory that joi exists.

Here is my Jest config:

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "notify": true,
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      ".*": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "text",
      "cobertura"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test-env.js",
      "mock-local-storage",
      "./setupTests.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/Support/"
    ]
  }
```

**Here is the Jenkins pipeline script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def wraps(body) {
    wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'XTerm', 'defaultFg': 1, 'defaultBg': 2]) {
        wrap([$class: 'TimestamperBuildWrapper']) {
            body()
        }
    }
}

def notifySlack(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {
    // Build status of null means success.
    buildStatus = buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESS'

    def color
    if (buildStatus == 'STARTED') {
        color = '#0673ce'
        wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
        msg = "${buildStatus}: ${env.JOB_NAME} - #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - `${env.ENVIRONMENT}` Started by user ${BUILD_USER}"
        }
    } else if (buildStatus == 'SUCCESS') {
        color = '#3ce04a'
        msg = "${buildStatus}: ${env.JOB_NAME} - #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - `${env.ENVIRONMENT}`\n ${env.BUILD_URL}"
    } else if (buildStatus == 'UNSTABLE') {
        color = '#d14536'
        msg = "${buildStatus}: ${env.JOB_NAME} - #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - `${env.ENVIRONMENT}`\n ${env.BUILD_URL}"
    } else {
        color = '#d14536'
        msg = "${buildStatus}: ${env.JOB_NAME} - #${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - `${env.ENVIRONMENT}`\n ${env.BUILD_URL}"
    }

    print msg
    slackSend(color: color, message: msg)
}

node() {
    try{
        notifySlack()
        wraps {
            stage('Clear Workspace') {
                deleteDir()
            }

            stage('Docker cleanup'){
                build job: 'cleanup-docker'
            }

            stage('Terraform build for Staging Environment'){
                if(env.Environment == 'STAGING'){
                    build job: 'BUILD-Terraform-Env',
                        parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'BRANCH', value: String.valueOf(BRANCH)]]
                }
            }

            stage('SCM Checkout') {
                checkout([
                    $class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/${BRANCH}']],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: '${GIT_SERVER}',credentialsId:'xxxxxxx']]
                ])
            }

            stage('Git Config'){
                sh "git config push.default current"
            }

            stage('Dist Cleanup'){
                dir ('assets') {
                    sh "rm -rf dist"
                }
            }

         stage('NPM Install & Test'){
             try {
                 dir ('assets') {
                    sh "npm i"
                    sh "npm run test"
                 }
                }
            finally {
                 [$class: 'CoberturaPublisher', coberturaReportFile: 'output/coverage/jest/cobertura-coverage.xml']
            }
         }

            stage('NPM Build'){
                dir ('assets') {
                    sh "npm run build"
                }
            }

            stage('Docker Build and Publish'){
                app = docker.build("myapp", "-f Dockerfile-ECS --pull --rm .")
                sh "`aws ecr get-login --region eu-west-1`"
                docker.withRegistry('https://9871259817.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com') {
                    app.push("${BRANCH}-${BUILD_NUMBER}")
                }
            }

            stage('Deploy on ECS'){
                sh "ecs deploy --region eu-west-1 MYAPP-\${Environment} newjavascript-app -t \${BRANCH}-\${BUILD_NUMBER} --timeout 600 --ignore-warnings"
            }

            stage('Version Bump'){
                if(env.Environment == 'PROD'){
                    dir ('assets') {
                        sh "npm run patch"
                    }
                }
            }

            stage('Git Push'){
                sh "git push origin HEAD:\${BRANCH}"
                sh "git push --tags"
            }

            stage('Docker cleanup'){
                build job: 'cleanup-docker'
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        throw e
    } finally {
        notifySlack(currentBuild.result)
    }
}
```

Comment: could you share your jenkins pipeline?

Comment: I just added the stages around the test, does that help?

Comment: in fact, I wanted to know on which image docker the pipeline runs, could you share all the pipeline or just the node directive.

Comment: okay, i've included the whole pipeline script above

Comment: how didi you check that `joi `package was in `\node_modules `?

Comment: To check I logged into the jenkins machine and went to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myapp-pipeline/assets ...
I was thinking maybe it could be some path issue since my dev env is Mac while Jenkins runs in Ubuntu machine....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181063/discussion-between-andolsi-zied-and-aaron).